# How to convert a filtered HTTP GET string to work with CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a project that uses RESO API and the companies documentation is a bit confusing; they show an example of a GET request link this:

```
GET https://www.perchwell.com/api/v1/OData/{system}/Property?$filter=StandardStatus eq 'Active'
```

Ultimately, I need to convert it to a PHP cURL request, which I've done to a certain degree. When I remove the `eq 'Active'` part I can make it work, but I'm not sure how to convert that to be using in PHP. Here is my cURL request that works, minus the active filter:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://www.perchwell.com/api/v1/OData/{system}/Property );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer 0000x0000x0000x0000';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error( $ch );
}
curl_close( $ch );
```

So I'm just confused on how and where I add `eq 'Active'`.

Comment: What's wrong with `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.perchwell.com/api/v1/OData/{system}/Property?$filter=StandardStatus eq 'Active'" );` ? It's part of the URL, so you can just append it to the URL.

Comment: Actually you might need to escape the `$` otherwise PHP would try to interpret there being a variable called `$filter` you want to interpolate into the string. So try `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.perchwell.com/api/v1/OData/{system}/Property?\$filter=StandardStatus eq 'Active'" );`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work; I tried both variations.

Comment: Didn't work how exactly? What problem occurs? Be clear and specific when describing the problem, because we cannot necessarily guess.

Comment: It simply fails. No message is returned. The spaces are the issues.

Comment: Ah of course. Have you tried URL-encoding them?

Comment: What ADyson probably means: "URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20." So have you tried using %20 for spaces?

Answer (score 0):

thats probably a misspelling of e.g meaning for example what the StandardStatus value could be, I would try

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.perchwell.com/api/v1/OData/{system}/Property?$filter=Active' );
```

or

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.perchwell.com/api/v1/OData/{system}/Property?filter=Active' );
```

hopefully one of these works